# An increasing Sequence

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+1}{2},\ n\ge0$ where $a_0\leq 1$, $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence.

**Proof.** We construct the Proof by recourse to *Mathematical Induction*. Let $n$ be arbitrary and assume that $n\in\{0,1,2,...\}$ assume further that $a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}$, now consider the term $a_{n+2}$ from defintion we see that 
$a_{n+2} = \frac{a_{n+1}+1}{2}$ furthermore from our use of the inductive hypothesis it follows that $\frac{a_n+1}{2}\leq\frac{a_{n+1}+1}{2}$, which we recognise as $a_{n+1}\leq a_{n+2}$ we may summarize that
$$\forall n\in\{0,1,2,...\}(a_n\leq a_{n+1}\implies a_{n+1}\leq a_{n+2})\tag{1}$$

Now assume for the purpose of contradiction that $a_0> a_1=\frac{a_0+1}{2}$ it then follows that $2a_0>a_0+1$ implying $a_0>1$ resulting in a contradiction establishing the basis step, this together with $(1)$ implies that 
$$\forall n\in\{0,1,2,...\}(a_n\leq a_{n+1})\tag{2}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me! I would explain further how $\frac{a_n+1}{2} \leq \frac{a_{n+1} +1}{2}$.

Comment: There's also a geometric interpretation. You start at a point and at every step your new location is in the middle of your current location and $1$, halving the distance between your current point and $1$. Since you started below $1$ you will always increase. Less formal but more intuitive.